# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax, error-handling

When I ran the javascript console on chrome it came up with uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier,I was hoping someone could help me figure out why this error keeps coming up it would be much appreciated

here is the line of code:

```
while( ship1[Y][X]=="#" || ship1[Y+1][X]=="#" || ship2[Y][X]=="#" || ship2[Y+1][X] =="X" ship3[Y][X]=="#" || ship3[Y+1][X] =="X");
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Tip: Don't use long statements like that. If you have to, split them into multiple lines. Your sanity will thank you.

Comment: Just as a note, why do you have a `;` at the end of the while ? You know that will create a while loop with an empty block of code which means it will make an infinite loop.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a `||` operator between `ship2[Y+1][X] =="X"` and `ship3[Y][X]=="#"`